# codename one google-services.json and build.gradle usage

Tags: android, codenameone, google-play-services

I want to develop a new application using codename one, but before i start coding i have some questions which i have because this new app needs to use google-services APIS.

1. In codename one, how do you include a google-services.json file? (In android studio  this goes on "App" directory)
2. How do you add content or modify build.gradle files?(both app build.gradle and project build.gradle), i need to add the reference to the google-services.json file, and some dependencies, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. We build the native app for you and add those files including set the build files.

You can explicitly pick specific google services using the [build hints](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html) in the project when targeting Android but all of those things are for Android.

If you would explain the dependencies we can discuss how you add them in a way that works in all of the supported platforms.

Comment: Thank you so much for  your help, my specific use case is to use firebase on CN1, and they instructions when using android studio are:

1) You register your new app on their site, your package name and your development SSHA key and this will generate a specific google-services.json file, you then copy the generated file to your App folder so thats why i want to find the way to include this  specific generated google-services.json on the equivalent App folder on CN1

Comment: 2) The firebase instructions also add the following content to the gradle files(one app level  build.gradle and one project level build.gradle) so i dont know in which of the 2 files codename one adds it when you use the build hints(also im not so familiar with gradle to know if i can use only one of these).

In the app level build.gradle the instructions say to add :
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'   

to the dependencies section, and to add:

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

To the end of file.

Comment: And to add :
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' 

To the dependencies section of the build.gradle project level file.

Comment: You are looking at the Android integration which can work for Android but then when you will want to use it in iOS you will run into other problems there (not to mention Windows UWP, JavaScript,  Desktop etc.). I would recommend the parse library: https://github.com/sidiabale/parse4cn1/ If you still want to use firebase you could look at the parse integration as a guide to implementing firebase, it's non trivial

Comment: Thank you so much , i will give the parse library a try, i wasnt aware of its existence.

Comment: Hi Shai ,can you help me with this question? the idea of using firebase was because of the push notifications, i took your suggestion of trying parse4cn1 but they currently dont support push for parse server, and parse.com will be closed soon. Do  you have any suggestion to push notifications on CN1 when having only a basic subscription? I really love CN1 and want to use it but the app needs push notifications and cant upgrade to a pro account.

Comment: And in case  theres no suggestion for push notifications, i'll have to go native for the push notifications and would love to develop the rest of the app on CN1 so it takes me back to my original questions, how can i include the personalized google-services.json that firebase generates for my App(google says it needs to be stored in the App folder )?  And which of the 2 build.gradle fliles that the basic app scheleton uses is affected by build argumetns in cn1?

Comment: Do you think an approach like "develop rest of the app in cn1" -> send build with "include resources" -> download project sources and import them on android studio(and xcode later) and develop the push functionality from the generated code will work?

Comment: That's not something we worked on or one of our goals. We do want to add additional push providers but only in the pro tier.